# In C language, normally this is how we take input using pointers, then why is it not working though ? Or am I wrong at some point?

Tags: c, pointers, struct

Usually we take input the following way when using pointers. But this time struct is used along with a pointer.

It works just like an array but is not taking input numbers after taking the size.

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<stdlib.h>

    struct point
    {
        int *data;
        int size;
    };

    int main()
    {
        struct point temp;
        scanf("%d",&temp.size);        

        printf("\n Enter data ---- \n");     
        for(int i=0 ; i<temp.size ; i++)
        {
            scanf("%d",(temp.data+i);
        }
    
        printf("\n The data is ----- \n");      
        for(int i=0 ; i<temp.size ; i++)
        {
            printf("%d",*(temp.data+i));
        }
    
        return 0;
    }
```

Can someone help....

Comment: Welcome to SO. We don't just use pointers but addresses of memory we allocated for that purpose.  Your pointer `data` does not point to any valid address.

Comment: "It works just like an array but ..." This is because pointers are not arrays. An array comes with all the memory it needs to store the values. A pointer only comes with an address. It is your job to make it point to a valid address of a large enough memory. Either by taking the address of a suitable variable or by dynamically allocating memory.

Comment: Where does `temp.data` point to?

Comment: Okay, yes got the point. Thanks your your help.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a complete answer, but it should point you into the right
direction.

Do you think that this slightly modified version of your program (that does not use a struct) works?

```
...
int *data;    // no struct used here
int size;

int main()
{
    scanf("%d",&size);        

    printf("\n Enter data ---- \n");     
    for(int i = 0 ; i < temp; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", (data+i);
    }
    ...
```